# Finding the Total Number of Prime Number from a List

Tags: c++

Currently, I am working on a program in C++ that reads a list of numbers from a file and outputs the total number of prime numbers in the file. I have gotten the wrong output twice and was wondering what I was doing wrong. Thank you for your help.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int);
int main() {
    string fileName;

    cout << "Please enter file name: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(fileName);
    if (!fin) {
        cout << "ERROR opening file" << fileName << "!!!" << endl;
    }

    int numPrime = 0, x;

    if (fin) {
        fin >> x;
        while (fin >> x) {
            if (isPrime(x) == true) {
                numPrime += 1;
            }
            else {
                numPrime += 0;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The total number of Prime Numbers is " << numPrime;

    }


    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int number) {
    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number - 1; divisor++) {
        if (number % divisor == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please provide examples of input-output that failed.

Comment: In the `if (fin)` statement, the first two actions are `fin >> x;` followed by `while (fin >> x) ...`.    That always discards the first value from the file, rather than checking it.  If that value is prime, your count will be off by one.

Comment: `for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number - 1;` -- you don't have to go that high, `number/2` is usually enough. or even `sqrt(number)`, if you are mathematically inclined =)

Comment: `if (isPrime(x) == true)` sounds a tad pleonastic =)

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the code, it was just missing the library string. You can add it in the beginning as `#include <string>`. You should also check if the text file is in the same directory as the source file. Moreover, make sure you enter the file with its format i.e. filename.txt

Hope that helps.